# How can I select a node with specific value of one attribute and maximum value of another attribute in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

For example, I have an XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <pos matnr="10017571" charg="1045825700" atwrt="108" labst="610" />
    <pos matnr="10017572" charg="1045825700" atwrt="108" labst="600" />
    <pos matnr="10017573" charg="1046186400" atwrt="108" labst="2730" />
    <pos matnr="10017573" charg="1046117000" atwrt="108" labst="5200" />
    <pos matnr="10017573" charg="1046055000" atwrt="108" labst="3507" />
    <pos matnr="10017574" charg="1045911400" atwrt="108" labst="50" />
    <pos matnr="10017574" charg="1046055000" atwrt="108" labst="14230" />
    <pos matnr="10017574" charg="1046117000" atwrt="108" labst="5500" />
    <pos matnr="10017574" charg="1046186400" atwrt="108" labst="2410" />
</list>
```

So, how can I select a node with specific value of one attribute and maximum value of another attribute in XPath? I need something like this (not works):

```
xmlDocZ.selectSingleNode("//pos[@matnr='10017574' and @labst[not(.>//@labst)]]");
```

Result must be:

```
<pos matnr="10017574" charg="1046055000" atwrt="108" labst="14230" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it by my self. This works fine:

```
xmlDocZ.selectSingleNode("//pos[@matnr='10017574' and @labst[not(.//pos[@matnr='10017574']/@labst)]]");
```